# Are there any resources with 3D models of every Chima piece w/prints?

Tags: ldraw, animation, chima

I'm looking for Chima pieces for a 3D animation project. Preferably compatible with Mecabricks. The characters in question do not matter though I would like if the resource had parts from an Ice Bear minifigure. I have tried LDraw and they only have parts for Worriz.